# I have 2 problems with my jQuery nav menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you resize the window to 600px or less I get 2 icons instead one, the hamburger menu.

The second problem is if the hamburger is clicked and closed, and I resize the window to over 600px the whole nav menu breaks.

here's the jQuery code

```
var nav = $('#menu > ul > li');
nav.find('li').hide();
nav.click(function () {
    nav.not(this).find('li').hide();
    $(this).find('li').slideToggle();
});

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("close").style.display = "block";
    $('#menu ul').slideToggle();
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("close").style.display = "none";
    $('#menu ul').slideToggle();
}

$(function () {
nav.mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find("li").slideUp();
    });
});
```

And you can see it in action here

https://www.myccandbuilds.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script listens for the screen size and makes the correct settings for over and under 600px

Add this code in your jQuery code:

```js
$(window).on('resize load', function () {
    var win = $(this);
    if (win.width() <= 600) {
        $('#close').attr("style", "display:none;");
        $('#open').attr("style", "display:block;");
        $('#menu ul').attr("style", "display:none;");
    } else {
        $('#close').attr("style", "display:block;");
        $('#menu ul').attr("style", "display:block;");
    }
});
```